# Problems with paste as values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, multiple-select

I have a problem in paste as values a multiple selection, this is what I have to do:
I have a spreadsheet, every cell has a formula in it and I want to create a macro which copy each cell and paste on itself as value (in order to remove every formula). The problem is that there are some cells which are locked, so if I try to copy and paste them excel returns an error and it stops the procedure.
Now I have two possibilities:

case 1: copy and past as values each cell individually, but I have a lot of cells and I have to do this procedure very often.

case 2: create a big selection which contains only the unlocked cells and then copy and paste them all togheter.

case 2 seems to be the better choice, but with excel I can't copy and paste multiple selection...does anyone have a tip for me?
I though to take the big fragmentary selection and copy and paste every block of the selection one by one, but I don't know if is it possible :(

Comment: Try doing what you need while recording a macro get the code auto generated and use it to adjust according to your need.

Comment: I'm asking an alternative method in order to do it quickly or a method in order to consider every block of the big selection separately. I'm not asking specifically the code

Comment: Unprotect the sheet prior to doing this then protect it back at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Loop throught every cell in selection and check if they are locked like this:

```
For Each Z In Selection
  if Not Z.Locked Then
   'do copy paste here
  End If
Next Z
```